# How to turn an Ubuntu Server with Bluetooth speakers into a cheap Google Nest speaker server?

Tags: server, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

Instead of purchasing several pricey Google Nest speakers, I think having multiple Bluetooth speakers connected to a single machine while treating each speaker as separate device in Google Home is a lot cheaper(and fun to work with... probably).

I have a Raspberry pi 4 with Ubuntu Server 21.04(totally headless) and it has Bluetooth 5.0/BLE. I read somewhere that BLE can connect to multiple to multiple devices simultaneously, so probably my idea could work.

Comment: Searching "Google Assistant for Raspberry Pi" turns up several results. Why not try there?

Comment: @Jos I already tried a tutorial and skipped to speaker part(I don't need the google assistant part) but it is already failing. I was able to connect the Bluetooth speaker but when testing it using "speaker-test -t wav", it doesn't work at all. Lots of RPi-related tutorials doesn't work with Ubuntu, so it is better to find Ubuntu-centric tutorials than RPi ones.